# Monthly Costs to be received Query - Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

on Oracle 11g Database I have the following tables containing:

1) The planned monthly costs that will be invoiced by collaborators.

MONTH: monthly competence of the cost

AMOUNT: amount of costs related to this month

2) The monthly invoices amount received by collaborators.

MONTH: monthly competence of the invoice

AMOUNT: amount of the invoices related to this month

Considering this example:

Table 1 (planned costs):

> JAN-2013 10,000
>   FEB-2013 10,000
>   MAR-2013 10,000
>   APR-2013 10,000
>   MAY-2013 10,000
>   JUN-2013 10,000

Table 2 (actual invoices):

> MAR-2013 35,000

Query result should be:

> APR-2013 5,000
>   MAY-2013 10,000
>   JUN-2013 10,000

Any hints?

Thanks
Wile E.

Comment: Will there be more than one cost or invoice record per month? In other words, do you need to SUM by month before applying the calculation to get the result? Also, if you have other columns involved now's the time to show them - the answer to this will be a somewhat involved analytic query, and if there are any grouping or other special requirements it's best if they're known right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information you provided the following query should generate the results you want.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(month, 'MON-YYYY'),
       DECODE(SIGN(planned_amount-(total_planned_amount-total_actual_amount)),
              -1, planned_amount,
                  total_planned_amount-total_actual_amount) result
  FROM (
SELECT month,
       SUM(planned_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY month) planned_amount,
       SUM(planned_amount) OVER (ORDER BY month) total_planned_amount,
       total_actual_amount
  FROM (SELECT month,
               planned_amount,
               total_actual_amount
          FROM (SELECT TRUNC(month, 'MM') month,
                       SUM(amount) planned_amount
                  FROM planned
                 GROUP BY TRUNC(month, 'MM')
                ),
                (SELECT NVL(SUM(amount), 0) total_actual_amount
                  FROM actual
                )
       )
    )
 WHERE total_planned_amount - total_actual_amount > 0
 ORDER BY month
```

The inner query uses a Cartesian join to create a list of each month, along with the planned amount for that month and the sum of all the invoices.

```
Month         planned_amount     total_actual_amount
Jan-2013      10000              35000
Feb-2013      10000              35000
Mar-2013      10000              35000
Apr-2013      10000              35000
May-2013      10000              35000
Jun-2013      10000              35000
```

It then performs another query to calculate the running total of the planned amounts.

```
Month       planned_amount    total_planned_amount   total_actual_amount
Jan-2013      10000           10000                  35000
Feb-2013      10000           20000                  35000
Mar-2013      10000           30000                  35000
Apr-2013      10000           40000                  35000
May-2013      10000           50000                  35000
Jun-2013      10000           60000                  35000
```

It then limits the results to only those whose *total_planned_amount* is greater than the *total_actual_amount* and for each month returns the **lesser** of either the *planned_amount,* or the difference between the *total_planned_amount* and the *total_actual_amount*

I hope that makes sense.